# gitignore for vim plugin

Tags: git, vim, plugins, gitignore

I'm about to write my first vim plugin/script. As I like to write and simultaneously practice with Git, I need a .gitignore file specified for this issue.
Is there something like a template of a .gitignore file or do I have to write it myself? Are there any suggestions on how a proper .gitignore file for the sake of a vim plugin/script could look like?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Gitignore file should be tailored according to what you want specifically. Though you can find a lot of gitignore templates if you google. https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: I'm aware of that but I don't know which one is the best for writing a vim plugin

Comment: You'll discover your needs as you go.

Comment: I've written a couple of Vim plugins (though not well-known or large), and they don't have or need a `.gitignore` file. Your needs may differ depending on what you are creating. As @romainl says, you will discover that as you do your development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @romainl pointed out, your .gitignore will be specific to the technologies that you are using, but to get some ideas for how these files generally look check out: https://www.gitignore.io/

I would recommend adding patterns to your .gitignore and adding files that you think will match those patterns to your repo to verify that you understand how the pattern matching works.

To verify, do a "git status" and see if the file you just added is showing as a change or not. If you don't see the file, then you know the .gitignore is working.

In general, if you have certain type of files you want to ignore; for example for *.foo* files, you will want a pattern like:

```
*.foo
```

If you have a particular directory that you want to ignore, for example a directory called *dist*, you will want a pattern like this:

```
dist
```

Read this link for general information about how .gitignore works: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore